# Multiline statements in Python

Tags: python, syntax, multiline

Previously, I thought I'd heard that using a backslash at the end of a line of Python code to continue on the next line was preferably avoided. What I remember being told was that enclosing things in parentheses was preferred.

I think I ran into at least one exception as pointed out to me in [Where is my syntax error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619235/where-is-my-syntax-error) , where the following is not a legitimate way of handling multiline statements:

```
(a =
  b)
```

What are the rules for preferred ways of handling multiline statements in Python?

Comment: Once you decide to forgo PEP8 for the sake of writing in your own style, then there are no preferred ways - just what you, the programmer, prefer.

If i do lots of assignments, i tend to like having my = operators all line up by using whitespace. Is it preferred? Yes. I prefer it. Is it PEP8? No way.

Answer (score 2):

> What I remember being told was that enclosing things in parentheses was preferred.

This is right, but it only works where it is syntactically allowed.

Expressions may be parethesed, but commands such as assignments may not be.

As you see,

```
(a =
  b)
```

doesn't work.

You could try

```
a = (
  b)
```

however, as there we have valid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The idea isn't to enclose an entire statement in parentheses. The idea is to break the line at the most natural possible point that's already inside parentheses, brackets, or braces. For example,

```
x = func(AbsurdlyLongArgumentNameSeriouslyItsWayTooLong1, AbsurdlyLongArgumentNameSeriouslyItsWayTooLong2)
```

could become

```
x = func(AbsurdlyLongArgumentNameSeriouslyItsWayTooLong1,
         AbsurdlyLongArgumentNameSeriouslyItsWayTooLong2)
```

and

```
l = [importantthing1, importantthing2, importantthing3, importantthing4, importantthing5, importantthing6]
```

could become

```
l = [
    importantthing1,
    importantthing2,
    importantthing3,
    importantthing4,
    importantthing5,
    importantthing6
]
```

If your long line does not already include a natural point to break it, you could introduce parentheses around some expression in that line:

```
number = thing1 + thing2 * thing3 / thing4 + thing5 * thing6 * thing7 * thing8 - thing9 / thing10 + thing11
```

could become

```
number = (thing1
          + thing2 * thing3 / thing4
          + thing5 * thing6 * thing7 * thing8
          - thing9 / thing10
          + thing11)
```